# Having a button on a child component run a function on the parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am currently stuck with a simple-looking issue but cannot find the wording.technicality behind solving it.

Essentially, I have a child component "project card" this card is rendered on my home page using

```
<div v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="index">
```

(pulled from an array called "projects" which contain objects).

Anyway, my issue is, I have a button on the "project card" component, and clicking on that I would like to run a function on the "home" page. (as it seems to make sense to control the array from there).

But, how do I do that? How do i make a button pressed on a child component fire a function on the parent?

Comment: This is called component event, here is the ref: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

Answer (score 0):

You need this in your child component:

```
this.$emit('myEvent')
```

Then you can do on your parent component:

```
<my-parent-component v-on:myEvent="doSomething"></my-parent-component>
```

You can read about firing events at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html . If this is the simple case then using event emiting is fine. But in another cases the better decision is using vuex.

Answer (score 0):

emit the event and register it in the child component using the "emits" property. Listen to the emitted event at the parent element where you have created the child instance and point the event listener to the function you want to execute.

For Eg.

Parent

```
<template>
   <child @close="closeIt"></child>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      methods: {
         closeIt() {
            //DO SOMETHING...
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

Child

```
<template>
   <button @click="closeInParent">Close</button>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      emits: ["close"],
      methods: {
         closeInParent() {
             this.$emit('close')
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```